# Accessing Apache server on an Android device locally

Tags: android, apache, client-server

I'm having trouble finding a way to accessing the page of a virtual host (and the default Apache index.html page) on my Android phone. My hosts file on both my Android and PC use 127.0.0.1 as localhost and domain1.com. I've restarted my Apache server on my PC, and I can access it fine on my PC's browser at domain1.com, but I can't seem to access it on my Android browser. I've tried a public IP address, domain1.com, domain1.com:8000, 127.0.0.1:8000, localhost:8000... but none seem to work. They work on my local PC, though. Here's my httpd.conf file:

```
<Directory /home/*/public_html/>
AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
<Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Limit>
<LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</LimitExcept>
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/home/*/public_html/domain1.com/public/"

Listen 8000
NameVirtualHost *:8000
<VirtualHost *:8000>
         ServerName domain1.com
         DocumentRoot /home/*/public_html/domain1.com/public
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: are you running apache on your `phone??!` or on your pc? plus you will never be able to contact remote server using address http://localhost... or 127.0.0.1 unless it's running locally....

Comment: I'm running it on my PC. Solved it anyway. Used local IP address of the PC from ifconfig. Cheers for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

`localhost` (a.k.a., `127.0.0.1`) on your phone points to your phone. `localhost` on your PC points to your PC. Your PC is not your phone. Your phone is not your PC.

If you want your phone's Web browser to access your PC, use the IP address of your PC in the URL, along with your desired port number (`8000`, apparently). Your PC's IP address is something other than `localhost`.

Comment: I feel stupid now. Didn't think of using the local IP address of the machine from ifconfig. Cheers!